# Series of $\Re[f(z)]$ and $\Im[f(z)]$ in $z=w\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

If I have an analytic function
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n\qquad |z|<R$$
and I want to calculate the real and imaginary parts I can consider the complex number $z$ in its polar form $(z=\rho e^{i\theta})$, so.
$$\Re[f(z)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Re\left[f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)\right]}{n!}\cos\left(n\theta\right)\rho^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Im\left[f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)\right]}{n!}\sin\left(n\theta\right)\rho^n\qquad \rho<R$$
$$\Im[f(z)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Re\left[f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)\right]}{n!}\sin\left(n\theta\right)\rho^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Im\left[f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)\right]}{n!}\cos\left(n\theta\right)\rho^n\qquad \rho<R$$

**Question**

If I wanted to make the series starting from a generic complex number $w\in\mathbb{C}$, what does the formula become?

In the real case I would have

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(w)}{n!}(z-w)^n\qquad |z-w|<R$$

In the complex case I have to do as before, but considering

$$\rho=|z-w|\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\theta=\text{arg}(z-w)$$
?

Comment: $\Re[f(z)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\rho^n\cos(n\theta)$ is wrong unless you assume that $f^{(n)}(0) \in \Bbb R$ for all $n$.